# Having trouble selecting CSS elements from a webpage using CSS Selector

Tags: c#, html, css, css-selectors

Currently I've been using CsQuery to do some webscraping.

The problem I'm at now is getting the actual correct CSS Selector to find the element inside the HTML code.

So in my webpage, this is the part I'm trying to parse through

```
<div id="workskin">
<div class="preface group">
    <h2 class="title heading">
        Pocket Healer
        </h2>
    <h3 class="byline heading">
        <a rel="author" href="/users/OverNoot/pseuds/OverNoot">OverNoot</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="summary module" role="complementary">
        <h3 class="heading">Summary:</h3>
        <blockquote class="userstuff">
            <p>
                "summary text goes here"
            </p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>

    <!-- Nothing else of importance past this point -->
```

And in my code, I attempt to highlight the important sections, but it doesn't seem to be working

````
    //Takes in URL from message
    //Loads up Ao3 page and parses for Title, Author, and Summary
    public String searchFanfic(String url)
    {
        String responseString = "```"; //Formatted message for discord bot to send to the channel

        CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl(url);
        CQ workskin = dom.Select("#workskin");

        var title = workskin.Find("h2.tile.heading").Text();

        var summary = workskin.Find("blockquote.userstuff").Text();

        var author = workskin.Find("h3.heading a[rel=author]").Text();

        responseString +=
            "Title: " + title +
            "\nAuthor: " + author +
            "\nsummary: " + summary;

        responseString += "```";
        return responseString;
    }
````

Comment: CsQuery is no longer being supported by its creator. Have you tried using his recommended app instead, https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp?

Comment: Okay I'll try it out. However in general the actual CSS Selector should be the same right? Or will that change too

Comment: Yep according to the CsQuery person the other app isn't a straight install (more configuration needed) but the process is the same.

Comment: You've got a typo in `"h2.tile.heading"`.

Comment: @jamesDonnelly thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately that didn't seem to be the overall problem